# how to create a prefilled array of float32 in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, float32

if I do:

```
import numpy as np

arr1=np.tile(0.75, 32)
```

I get a 32 element array of float64 initialized with the value 0.75.

How to do the same but get a float32 array?

Comment: `np.tile(np.float32(0.75), 32)`

Comment: You can use `np.full`, `np.full(32, 0.75, dtype=np.float32)`

Comment: I was about to suggest `np.ones(32, dtype=np.float32)*0.75` that is faster than `np.tile`, and `np.full` is even faster

Comment: this "seems" to work: np.tile(0.75, 32).astype(np.float32)

Comment: @mozway that code returns an array of float64 not float32

Comment: Out of curiosity, I've just tried out some ugly benchmark (aka `%timeit`). `tile` + casting : 6.55µs, `ones` with dtype : 3.44µs, `full` 2.13µs :)

Comment: ok.. then my problem is not this one... I am writing a WAV file using "soundfile". if I do f.write(float value)  in a loop, it works. if I pass to it a float32 array it does not. damn.

Comment: thanks everyone anyway

Answer (score 0):

All suggestion work but my program clearly was not related to this but to the soundfile library.
Anyway:

Solutions are:

```
np.tile(0.75, 32).astype(np.float32)
```

or

```
np.full(32, 0.75, dtype=np.float32)    # **FASTEST**
```

or

```
np.ones(32)*0.75
```